# Can't Save Image Blob

Tags: titanium

I am trying to save an image from the photo gallery to local storage so that I can load the image up across application sessions.  Once the user is done selecting the image, the following logic is executed.  On the simulator I see the error message is written out to the log.  Even though I am seeing the error message I think the image is still saved in the simulato because when I restart the application I am able to load the saved image.  When I run this on the device though, I still get the error message you see in the code below and the default background is loaded which indicates the write was not successful.

Can anyone see what I am doing wrong and why the image won't save successfully?

```
var image = i.media.imageAsResized(width, height);
backgroundImage.image = image;      
function SaveBackgroundImage(image)
        {
            var file = Ti.Filesystem.getFile(Titanium.Filesystem.applicationDataDirectory,W.CUSTOM_BACKGROUND);
            if(file.write(image, false))
            {
                W.analytics.remoteLog('Success Saving Background Image');
            }
            else
            {
                W.analytics.remoteLog('Error Saving Background Image');
            }
            file = null;            
        }
```

Comment: Can you define what "the error message" is?

Comment: Sorry, should have been more clear.  I don't get any exception thrown or error message returned.  When a call is made to the write method, it comes back as true or false indicating if it was successful or not.  In my case it comes back false but with no information returned or nothing written out to the console window.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try this Code:

```
var parent = Titanium.Filesystem.getApplicationDataDirectory();
var f = Titanium.Filesystem.getFile(parent, 'image_name.png');
f.write(image);
Ti.API.info(f.nativePath); // it will return the native path of image
```

In your code i thing you are not giving the type of the image (png/jpeg) thats why your getting error.